# XTEXT2- validation error after migration to XTEXT2

Tags: xtext

I met a strange error after migration to XTEXT2.

When I write three elements, one `IfEffectivePackageBlock` and define one `class` and its `subclass` extends it.

The code I wrote is very simple to replay the error. But it is fine in XTEXT 1.0

```
IfEffectivePackageBlock xxx{

}

class xx{
}

class xxxx extends xx{
}
```

The  grammer I using is listed below, it will popup the error I met.

```
 IfEffectivePackageBlock:
        'ifEffective' effectivityId=ID '{'
            (elements+=AbstractElement)*
        '}'
        ;   

    ClassDeclaration:
    'class' name=ID ('extends' superType=[ClassDeclaration])? '{' 
        (statements+=(   
                        FunctionDef |
                        ConfigurationEntryPoint 

                    )

        )*
    '}'
    ;
```

It will popup an window that warning me there is an internal error.
You can see it below.

[image: Bug image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your qualified name provider has to be updated. You'll have to return a qualified name instead of a string.